# Replacing faulty occupancy sensor

Tags: electrical, wiring

A bathroom occupancy sensor stopped working and I'm having trouble replacing it. Referring to the photo, the sensor is on the left and controls the same light as the switch on the right. Wiring is the same on both: two black wires and a ground. I tried a 3-pole sensor, capping the blue wire from the sensor, and it didn't work. I tried a single-pole sensor and it senses the motion (can hear the click) but doesn't turn the light on. Not sure what I'm missing but obviously have no idea what I'm doing wrong. What do I need to do to get a functioning occupancy sensor with this light switch configuration? (The middle switch is a separate bathroom fan that isn't meant to be connected to the sensor.)

[image]

Comment: What did the switch on the right do to the light originally?

Comment: Does the switch on the right control other circuits for that matter?

Comment: Is the lamp bad? A single pole and a click sounds like it is turning on.